# jQuery - Search through JSON array

Tags: jquery, html, json

I need to search through JSON data and find every object that contains the "kind" "playlist" and then go through the tracks and pull information which will be put into a hmtl list. The problem is that in some instances (depending on the type of URL) instead of a multidimensional array containing all the objects, the json information is just a singular object.

Below are the two url types.

This is a playlist which contains just one level of information.
http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/1980151.json?client_id=bcc776e7aa65dbc29c40ff21a1a94ecd

This is an array which contains just multiple playlists as objects.
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/dubstep/playlists.json?client_id=bcc776e7aa65dbc29c40ff21a1a94ecd

The current code I have is this:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/users/dubstep/playlists.json?client_id=bcc776e7aa65dbc29c40ff21a1a94ecd', { get_param: 'value' }, function(url_data) {
$.each(url_data, function (i, elem) {
    if (elem.kind === 'playlist') {
        $.each(elem.tracks, function (i, elem) {
            console.log(elem.title);
        });
    }
});
```

});

It **only** works when dealing with "user" urls where there are multiple playlists.

To sum up what my issue is, I need a way to search through all the levels of an array to find levels with the kind === playlist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for.

```
$.each(json, function (i, elem) {
    if (elem.kind === 'playlist') {
        $.each(elem.tracks, function (i, elem) {
            console.log(elem.title);
        });
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

This will work with either URL. Also, here's a fiddle with more a more advanced client-side output: http://jsfiddle.net/jTLvE/

```
var parse = function (json) {
    $.each(json, function (i, elem) {
        if (elem.kind === 'playlist') {
            $.each(elem.tracks, function (i, elem) {
                console.log(elem.title);
            });
        }
    });
},
parseReturnedData = function (json) {
    var isObject = (typeof json === 'object' && json instanceof Object),
        isArray = (typeof json === 'object' && json instanceof Array),
        newArray = [];
    if (isArray) {
        parse(json);
    } else if (isObject) {
        newArray.push(json);
        parse(newArray);
    }
};
```

Comment: This works perfectly when I have multiple playlists, perfectly! However if I use http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/1980151.json?client_id=bcc776e7aa65dbc29c40ff21a1a94ecd it won't work because "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'elem.kind')"

Comment: Wow, this went above and beyond the call! This is perfect. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [json path](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)? I used it and it's small and fast, especially for searching json trees (for searching and writing I'd use [flock](https://github.com/danstocker/flock) though).

Comment: I'd prefer to not have this code rely on any plugins or requirements aside from jquery as I'd like to use it as a standalone plugin.

Comment: I do understand your concerns; should you need to do json lookups I think it's worth checking these libraries out, but of course for a single case it may be an overkill.

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
var objJson = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
jQuery.each(objJson , function(i, val) {
      alert(val);
    });
```